# List of special/reserved attributes in R?

Tags: r, attributes

I'm learning about R attributes through the book 'Advanced R'. The question, as the title says, is how I can find what are the reserved attributes (those with some special properties). E.g:

```
structure(1:5, test.attribute = 'test')
```

Returns:

```
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> attr(,"test.attribute")
#> [1] "test"
```

But for:

```
structure(1:5, comment = 'my attribute')
```

It returns:

```
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

So I think 'comment' has something special attached to it as attribute name and I would like to find if there are more reserved words like this.

I have ended up looking in the source code (https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/27da0eac8bb84677002febcf12e6d61bb7358d89/src/main/attrib.c?) but I guess I don't have enough knowledge to understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Its a special attribute that doesn't get printed. There is even a dedicated [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/comment.html) to retrieve it and set it.